# How to solve the MATLAB low-level graphics error problem

Tags: matlab, opengl

When using **Matlab2018a** to view the graphical results, the following error occurred: `MATLAB encountered a low-level graphical error, which may cause incorrectness.`

Check out the MATLAB information below

```
opengl info
                          Version: ''
                           Vendor: ''
                         Renderer: 'None'
            RendererDriverVersion: ''
        RendererDriverReleaseDate: ''
                   MaxTextureSize: 0
                           Visual: ''
                         Software: 1
             HardwareSupportLevel: 'none'
        SupportsGraphicsSmoothing: 0
    SupportsDepthPeelTransparency: 0
       SupportsAlignVertexCenters: 0
                       Extensions: {}
               MaxFrameBufferSize: 0
```

The `opengl software` command appears: You cannot use OpenGL software to render while `UNIX` is running.
`opengl hardware` and `opengl hardwarebasic`  still show the top error

I don't know how to start to solve this problem.

So, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

> Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Maybe not a solution but rather a workaround, have you tried changing the renderer to 'painters'? set(gcf,'renderer','painters'); I also had some issues when using openGL in some of my projects, keep in mind that painters is quite slow when compared to openGL.

Comment: MATLAB GUI is terrible in ubuntu.... Source: been using it for 5 years..